# Dynamcially added class works on <td> but not on <tr>. Why?

Tags: javascript, class, dynamic

The function simply injects new rows into an empty table when the function is called.

it would seem that since the `<td>` class gets assigned properly, that the `<tr>` would also get assigned... but it doesn't!

```
var newRow = document.createElement("tr");

for (data in dataArray)
{
    var newName = document.createElement("td"); 

    newName.className = classNames[data];
    newName.innerHTML = dataArray[data];
    newRow.appendChild(newName);
    counter++;
}
document.getElementById("capturedData").appendChild(newRow);
var newRow2 = document.createElement("tr");
newRow2.class = "hiddenRow";

for (data in dataArray)
{
    var newData = document.createElement("td");
    var newDataField = document.createElement("input");

    newDataField.type = "hidden";
    newDataField.name = "name" + data;
    newDataField.value = dataArray[data];

    newData.class = classNames[data];
    newData.value = dataArray[data];

    newData.appendChild(newDataField);      
    newRow2.appendChild(newData);   
}
```

which is really weird. All the newly added `<td>` elements have their classes assigned and they show up in the DOM.  But the `<tr>` elements don't accept the class assignment and in the DOM they have no class.

Why is this? I've read about the purported asynchronicity of script execution, but surely this can't be the case, it would defeat the purpose, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DOM elements have no property `class`, because it is a reserved keyword. You are looking for `className`:

```
newRow2.className = "hiddenRow";
```

Same for the cell (`newData`). It works for your other cell because you are using `className` already:

```
newName.className = classNames[data];
```

Comment: don't know how i missed that.  guess since the debugger didn't flag it, i thought it was valid.  thank you much!  :D

Answer (score 1):

Use only **className**, not **class** . There is no class-property in `<TR>`.